# Linux Commands for Task

Tags: linux, centos-6, user, directory-listing, user-groups

I am working on a File server on cent OS but stuck with a simple process, some how I am getting no result maybe I am new Linux that's why can't figure it out. Please Need Help:

Here is what I want to Do :

> want to Create a directory in /home with name of first-dir, make permission like below
>
> - user jamy can execute a file
> - group member (webteam) of define can only read each other file or listing directory
> - other member (coders) can only read files and directory list."

Comment: It's a homework, right? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What did searching return?

Comment: ok By default I logged as root. I created the  dir. also created the user, group, other group. So now Should I have to login as user to give permission to folder, or can i do it as root

Comment: [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod), [chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown)

Comment: Ok Now Its clearing, Tried and worked thank you .